# How to hook logout action for frontend user in Typo3 v8 or v9

Tags: typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I am developing a Typo3 extension and I want to hook logout action of frontend user. I searched for a proper guide/tutorial and got a rough idea how can w dok that. I tried two methods:

1) **Using Logout_confirmed Hook** but it didn't work. Maybe I am missing something. What I did is...
I  mentioned below line in ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['felogin']['logout_confirmed'] = Vendor/Ext_key/Hooks/Logout::class.'->checklogout'
```

and  created a class at the given path Vendor/Ext_key/Hooks/Logout::class.'->checklogout'... But the flow never reaches the checklogout() method, when user hits logout. Can somebody tell what am I missing or doing wrong.

2) I tried intercepting logout request directly in a controller action by checking

```
            if ($_REQUEST['logintype'] == 'logout')
```

I can intercept this request but the user gets logged out and its data is cleared from the session before I intercept it in Controller. 
I have to set some values per user basis when a user hits logout, so I want to hook in between user hits logout and  before his session is cleared. So that I can access username and set values for that user accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the hooks in class `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Authentication\AbstractUserAuthentication` in method `logoff()`:

Register hook in your extension in `ext_localconf.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']
        ['SC_OPTIONS']
        ['t3lib/class.t3lib_userauth.php']
        ['logoff_pre_processing']
        [] = \Vendor\Extension\Hooks\FrontendLogoutHook::class . '->checklogout';
```

Add class `Vendor\Extension\Hooks\FrontendLogoutHook`:

```
class FrontendLogoutHook
{
    public function checklogout(array $ref, $userAuth)
    {
        $userId = $userAuth->getSession()->getUserId();

        if (
            $userAuth instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Authentication\FrontendUserAuthentication
            && $userAuth->getLoginFormData()['status'] == 'logout'
            && $userId
        ) {
            // ... do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The above example uses the hook `logoff_pre_processing` which is called before the logout happens, but there is also a hook after the logout (`logoff_post_processing`).

Make sure to delete the whole TYPO3 cache after adding the hook to the `ext_localconf.php`!